# Messed up color scheme in ReSharper C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, colors, resharper, resharper-c++

After upgrading to the latest ReSharper Ultimate version, my VS color scheme is kinda messed up. i have tried re-installing it, deleting the `VC12_Config` key from the registry and modify the "extensions changed file". If I suspend ReSharper my color scheme switches back to the default dark skin (which I want).

Here is what it looks like:

#### ReSharper on

[image: reshaper on]

#### ReSharper off

[image: reshaper off]

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: sorry, if it did not become clear. i want the default color scheme to work with resharper, as it did before.

Comment: Dark color schemes may be troublesome

Comment: Embedded images and other fixes

Comment: Why they think it's a good idea to replace the default colors without asking is beyond me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The colour scheme is not really messed up, Resharper has just added a few more colours, this is probably due to the Code Inspections (for C# anyway, I assume it is similar for C++). To disable this, go to: `Resharper`->`Options...`->`Code Inspection`->`Settings` and uncheck the 'Color identifiers'

[image]

EDIT: The above was for C# and Resharper 8.2, for C++ and Resharper 9 the setting is here:

[image]

Comment: well almost! i had to deactivate this for c++. the setting can be found here: http://oi62.tinypic.com/2j69xet.jpg thank you!

Comment: Added your image to the answer as I'm not using Resharper 9 yet.

Comment: When they change my colors without asking to something that I don't want, yes I do consider that "messed up".  I agree with OP.